# Cannot get Prisma to work with an existing MySQL DB that has data on it

Tags: docker-compose, graphql, prisma, prisma-graphql

First of all we have a MySQL DB setup on Heroku that already has data on it. I'm trying to add the Prisma layer on top of our DB.

My docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
services:
  prisma:
    image: prismagraphql/prisma:1.34
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "4466:4466"
    environment:
      PRISMA_CONFIG: |
        port: 4466
        # uncomment the next line and provide the env var PRISMA_MANAGEMENT_API_SECRET=my-secret to activate cluster security
        # managementApiSecret: my-secret
        databases:
          default:
            connector: mysql
            host: 
            database: 
            user: user 
            password: 
            rawAccess: true
            port: '3306'
            migrations: false
```

Prisma.yml

```
# The HTTP endpoint for Prisma API
endpoint: http://localhost:4466

# Points to the file that contains your datamodel
datamodel: datamodel.prisma

# Specifies language and location for the generated Prisma Client
generate:
  - generator: javascript-client
    output: ./generated/prisma-client/
```

I go through `prisma init` and it connects to the DB and sets up the datamodel as it should, from what it seems like.

After `docker-compose up -d` I run `prisma deploy` and it hits me with

> Could not connect to server at http://localhost:4466. Please check if
>   your server is running.

I run `systemctl status docker` and the docker is running as it should.

I then run `docker-compose logs` and I get back this

> Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException:
>   (conn=10044859) Access denied for user 'user'@'%' to database 'prisma'

So from reading around does prisma need the DB user to have the privileges to create a new schema in the DB for its management purposes?

I have no clue where to go from here. If I'm doing something wrong here, the help would be much appreciated!

Btw: SSL is not active on the DB so there is no need for it to be true.